# Deploy PHP application with extension mongo into heroku 2015

Tags: php, mongodb, heroku

I've just deployed php application into heroku with extension mongo db. 
In previous (11/2014), it's ok. 
But currently I received error messsage: The requested php extension ext-mongo * is missing from your system.

Here is the structure of project on github (using to deploy into heroku):

```
Root
php.ini
composer.json
composer.lock
Procfile
MySources
ext 
   mongo.so (this file is located inside ext folder).
```

php.ini:

```
extension_dir="/app/ext/"
extension=mongo.so
```

composer.json:

```
{
  "require" : {
    "silex/silex": "~1.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.7",
    "ext-mongo": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
  }
}
```

Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
```

Any one can help me to configure or sugguest me to resolve this problem? Deploy with the lasted heroku and php 5.6.7.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `ext` folder (because the extension is already available on Heroku), and you don't need the `php.ini`, which doesn't have any effect anyway, because you're not configuring Heroku to use it.

You need to run `composer update` so the `ext-mongo` requirement gets "frozen" to `composer.lock`.

If you don't have that extension installed locally on your system, then you should install it (along with a MongoDB server), because you *really* want to test your code locally before you blindly push it up to Heroku to see whether it works or not.

If, for any reason, you can't do that, a `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` will prevent "The requested php extension ext-mongo * is missing from your system" to happen on your local machine, and generate the correct `composer.lock` even if the extension is missing.

This is, by the way, all clearly documented here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions